# Is Zombie-pigman aggro contagious?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I attack a zombie pigman, it'll attack me. If I do this on a server will it attack other players, or just me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Pigman):

> If a player attacks a zombie pigman in multiplayer, they turn hostile
> to ALL players. If the player who attacked them dies or goes away, the
> zombie pigmen attack the next player who is closest to them.

Answer (score 2):

Attacking zombie pigman makes them hostile, which means they will attack everyone that they see just like normal zombies, until they die.